# setToAddress issue in email service

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

I just need to add the setToadrress to singlemessages email service,,objIDs holds the id's to add for setToaddress
can anyone help me

```
  public void sendEmail(){
        Set<ID> objIDs = new Set<ID>();  
        listOfRecipientsIsEmpty = true;
        objIDs.addAll(getIncludedAccountTeamMemberID(false));
        objIDs.addAll(getIncludedObjectTeamMemberID(stdController.getID()));
                List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> singleMessages=new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

      //  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] singleMessages=new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{};

        system.debug('### objIDs: ' + objIDs);

             if(objIDs!=null && objIDs.size()!=0){
            singleMessages.addAll(createSingleEmailMessagesForAccountTeamMembers(objIDs ,stdController.getID(),this.templateID));
            listOfRecipientsIsEmpty = false;
        }

        system.debug('### notificationGroupRowList: ' + notificationGroupRowList);
        system.debug('### meRowList: ' + meRowList);

        if(meRowList.get(0).include==true){
            Set<Id> merckEmployeeIds = new Set<Id>();      
            for(NotificationGroupRow groupRow : notificationGroupRowList){
                merckEmployeeIds.addAll(groupRow.merckEmployeeIDs);              
            }
            singleMessages.add(createSingleEmailMessageForMerckEmployees(stdController.getID(),this.templateID,merckEmployeeIds,false));            
            listOfRecipientsIsEmpty = false;
        }

        if(notificationMemberRowList.get(0).include==true){
            Set<Id> notificationGroupMemberSet = new Set<Id>();            
            for(NotificationGroupRow groupRow : notificationGroupRowList){
                notificationGroupMemberSet.addAll(groupRow.notificationGroupMember);
            }
            singleMessages.add(createSingleEmailMessageForMerckEmployees(stdController.getID(),this.templateID,notificationGroupMemberSet,true));
            listOfRecipientsIsEmpty = false;
        }  

          List<string> UserEmail = new List<string>();

    for (User u : [select id, Email from User where Id in :objIDs]){
       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        UserEmail.add(u.Email);
          email.setToAddresses(UserEmail);
            singleMessages.add(email);

    }

        system.debug('### singleMessages: ' + singleMessages);

        system.debug('### listOfRecipientsIsEmpty: ' + listOfRecipientsIsEmpty);

        if(singleMessages!=null && singleMessages.size()!=0){
            try{
                Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results=Messaging.sendEmail(singleMessages);
                if (!results.get(0).isSuccess()) {
                    this.isSent = false; /* Ewa Byra (ewa.byra@outbox.pl) | show popup message on page when emails was not send | 13/06/2013 */
                    System.StatusCode statusCode = results.get(0).getErrors()[0].getStatusCode();
                    String errorMessage = results.get(0).getErrors()[0].getMessage();
                    system.debug(statusCode + ' | '+errorMessage );
                }else{
                    this.isSent = true; /* Ewa Byra (ewa.byra@outbox.pl) | no popup message on page when emails was not send | 13/06/2013 */
                    system.debug('asd: '+singleMessages.get(0).getHTMLBody());
                    system.debug('asd2: '+singleMessages.get(0).getPlainTextBody());
                    createActivityRecord(stdController.getID(),objIDs,singleMessages.get(0).getPlainTextBody());
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                this.isSent = false; /* Ewa Byra (ewa.byra@outbox.pl) | show popup message on page when emails was not send | 13/06/2013 */
                system.debug(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not forget to mark answer as solved because it might be useful for others !!

Answer (score 0):

Your trying setToAddresses to a List. 
First create and assign setToAddresses single instance **Email** , Then add 
 **Email** instance to an List **singleMessages**

```
    Set<ID> objIDs = new Set<ID>(); 
  //objIDs is used to store the user Id's
  // i have two id's  in ObjIDs . example:0054E000001jEoUQAU,0054E000001lC07QAE;

   List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> singleMessages=new 
   List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for(User u : [select id, Email from User where Id in :objIDs]){
       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
       email.setToAddresses(u.Email);
       singleMessages.add(email);
    }
    Messaging.sendEmail(singleMessages);
```

**Edited More**

You can directly pass List of address to setToAddresses method

> ```
>  List<String> listIds = new List<String>();
>      for(User u : [select id, Email from User where Id in :objIDs])
>          listIds.add(u.Email);
>     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
>     email.setToAddresses(listIds);
>     singleMessages.add(email);
> ```

Comment: thanks Nitesh, i tried with the given code but still it is throwing another exception. i have posted controller method code can you please look into it. I just need to add the  setToadrress to singlemessages email service,,objIDs  holds the id's to add  for setToaddress

Comment: can you tell me which line your getting error ? And Error message.

Comment: I am getting below exception on last line system.debug(e); System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 2; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Either the plain text body or html body must be supplied: []

Comment: createSingleEmailMessagesForAccountTeamMembers more About this function .

Comment: Can't identify what you are going to achieve actually, i need more explanation what your going to do inside?

Comment: I need to add the setToAdress to the above singleMessages email service, and  i need to assign setToaddress value as objIDs it has the Id's to whoom to send the email

Comment: I have edited to my answer. please find .

Answer (score 0):

Do not use setToAddress to email users. There are governor limits to how many emails you can send to daily by email address. Instead, use setTargetObjectId, which will not consume this limit when users are set.

```
for (User u : [select id, Email from User where Id in :objIDs]){
   Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
   email.setTargetObjectId(u.Id);
   // Remember to call setTemplateId or setSubject, 
   // and setPlainTextBody or setHtmlBody (or both)
   singleMessages.add(email);
}
```